# Wrong encoding with JSON parsing

Tags: ruby, json, encoding, utf-8, jruby

I have a json file, which I want to parse using JRuby, so I'm doing this:

```
file = File.read(file_name)
tweets = JSON.parse(file)
```

But when I print `tweets`, this is what I'm getting:

```
{"text"=>"@avaifc esse Eduardo Neto se o FelipÃ£o vÃª mele jogando Ã© capa de desconvidar alguÃ©m para o por no lugar." }
```

Any help?

Comment: What encoding is the file written as?

Comment: @MattBall: Pretty sure it's UTF-8, as it has one byte for ASCII range and two bytes for Spanish-specific characters.

Comment: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: Have you considered that the problem could be in the printing instead of the reading? How do you print them?

Comment: As Erwin mentioned, try `print File.read(file_name)` inside of `irb`. This loads/prints UTF-8 characters perfectly on my machine.

Comment: I'm opening the file guys. It's the same as printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
File.read(file_name, :encoding => 'UTF-8')
```